# Установка на этот том невозможна, так как на компьютере недостаточно разделов прошивки

Tags: xcode, swift, mac, обновление, sierra

Всем привет, поставил себе на виртуальную машину macOS Sierra 10.12. Попытался скачать xcode, но отобразилось предупреждение, что xcode работает на более новых версиях. Пытаюсь обновить, но мне выдаёт ошибку (ниже в скриншоте)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите кто-нибудь, пожалуйста, как решить проблему или как можно скачать более старую версию xcode. 
Зарание спасибо)
з.ы Гугл не помог

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из AppStore должна скачиваться версия Xcode, которая запустится на этой версии. Также на https://developer.apple.com/download/ можете скачать любую версию по желанию. Для Sierra версия Xcode 9.2 и ниже.

По поводу обновления проблем много может быть, возможно неправильно определяет место, возможно еще что. Можете попробовать с нуля установить или скачать на определенных ресурсах готовую для виртуалки.

Comment: По ссылке которую вы скинули есть только 2 версии. 9.3 и 9.4 бета(

Comment: @ПавелКушнеревич в самом низу там секция "Don’t see what you’re looking for?
 See more downloads"